# SharePoint 2013: Execute JavaScript in a form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am new to SharePoint and I like to execute some custom JavaScript on a form. In this [articel](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/10/29/how-to-insert-custom-javascript-code-in-sharepoint-2013-pages-part-i/) the author outlines an approach where he adds a "Script Editor" webpart to the form that hosts the html & JavaScript.

This approach seems to be odd, because the Script is not executed as part of the form iteself (see webpart contains the entire html including head, body....).

So my questions is: How do I execute custom JavaScript on a form? An what is the best approach regarding the deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a ContentEditorWebPart is a bit like loading an entire page into a DIV element. Because of this, you can access all the "Parent's" elements easily using `document.getElementById` selectors.

This practice is pretty widespread throughout the industry as it is the only way of injecting html/javascript without using SharePoint Designer or placing files in the SharePoint hive.

Usually you create a html or js file. Add it to a document library with version control enabled, and then reference that page from the ContentEditorWebPart

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about server side development, here's my favorite method: [JSLink and Display Templates](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1-overview-url-tokens-and-applying-jslink-to-objects.html). By using this approach you have a high degree of control ever the scope where you'd like to load your JavaScript code.

> There are a vast number of objects you can attach JSLink references to
>   but the ones we are really interested are:
>
> - Site Columns
> - Content Types
> - List Views
> - **List Forms (e.g. New / Edit / Display forms)**
> - List View Web Parts
> - List Form Web Parts

Regarding the deployment, it depends on the scope you would like to apply:

> When you are constructing your JSLink URL there are a number of tokens
>   you can take advantage of:
>
> - **~site** – reference to the current SharePoint site (or “Web”)
> - **~sitecollection** – reference to the current SharePoint site collection (or “Site”)
> - **~layouts** – version specific reference to the web application Layouts folder (so it will automatically swap out /_layouts/14 or /_layouts/15
>     for you)
> - **~sitecollectionlayouts** – reference to the layouts folder in the current site collection (e.g. /sites/team/_layouts/15)
> - **~sitelayouts** – reference to the layouts folder in the current site (e.g. /sites/teams/subsite/_layouts/15)

Basically, I'd recommend you to go through all the parts of the aforementioned tutorial in order to understand the power of JSLink.